# What's the purpose of cron.daily folder in Ubuntu distro

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a cron job that I put in cron.daily folder on my UBuntu server. I assumed that this would run daily by default, but found that it was actually not running when I checked /var/log/syslog. Did I make a wrong assumption? Do I need to configure the script with crontab -e.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By the run-parts used by ubuntu and debian cron:

- File shouldn't have an extension.
- File should be chmod 755.

And just to be sure:

- /etc/crontab should have a line for launch the cron.daily scripts
- cron should be running in the process table.

Comment: File does not have extension and permissions are set to 755. cron is running verified, ps -eaf | grep cron and my crontab file is.   _italic_ **bold** 'SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user command
17 * * * * root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )...' _italic_ **bold**

Comment: Have you tried restarting crond? In theory it should work without it but I noticed that on rhel/centos it is not always picking up changes without restart.

Answer (score 0):

Your cronjob under `/etc/cron.daily/script` has to be executable. Also it has to be shell script. If you want to run Perl for instance, you have to call it from within the cronjob shell script. Make sure anacron is not on the way and the others cron.daily jobs run as specified.

Comment: Anacron is in there, should I take that out?    25 6 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )

Comment: @archie: Does the others daily cronjobs run at 6:25am? If not - then anacron messes things up. Do you have issues with them as well?

Comment: Cron did run at 6:25 am , my job failed with the info below. CRON[18056]: (CRON) error (grandchild #18057 failed with exit status 1)

Comment: The error was No MTA installed, discarding output